# Select column names that cannot be null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several tables with 30+ columns each and I would like to easily get the names of the columns that do not allow for null values.

Is there a simple query that can do this for a table?

Something like `describe [table_name]` but that only shows required columns, and not necessarily other info about the columns (like type) although that could be nice too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
USE [dbtest]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Event]
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(10) NULL
)
GO

------------------------------------------------

USE [dbtest] --- !!!
GO

SELECT name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Event', 'U')
    AND is_nullable = 0
```

Output -

```
name
-----------
ID
```

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, returning 1 column 'name' that I assume would list the column names but it is empty for me.  It's still empty when removing the AND clause so something must be wrong as there are definitely columns in the table.  Here is my query:  

SELECT name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbname.dbo.Event', 'U')
    AND is_nullable = 1

Comment: Try to directly set `USE db`

Comment: Just a note, the question was to show columns that can NOT be null, in which case set `is_nullable = 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
WHERE table_name = 'test1'
    AND is_nullable = 'no'
```

Answer (score 1):

use the sys.tables and sys.columns virtual tables:

```
select T.name as [TableName], C.name As [ColumnName]
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.tables t
    on t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'MyTable' AND c.is_nullable = 0 AND t.type = 'U'
```